# Change data connection runtime

Tags: powerapps

Maybe this is something trivial, but I couldn't figure it out.
I would like to publish an app that will be used from a SharePoint sites using their local resources. Like each page has a "customers" list and the app should always work with that. Can check somehow check this on startup and modify the connections?